# Export from SQL Server 2008 to Excel 2013 put results on specific cell

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm using SQL Server 2008 and Excel 2013. I have a query to return count, and now I'm looking to export the results to an Excel sheet that is already created and put the results in a specific cell. Can we do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a loaded question for an exact answer, but yes it is possible.

You don't really *export* from SQL. Instead you connect your workbook to SQL and *pull* data into a worksheet. This doesn't have to be your main worksheet. You can pull into a "staging area" and then manipulate however you need to.

Here is a good starting point: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Connect-a-SQL-Server-database-to-your-workbook-22c39d8d-5b60-4d7e-9d4b-ce6680d43bad